# RGB to YUV 420P image conversion in Go

Tags: image, go, rgb, yuv, ycbcr

I am wondering, how can I perform conversion from RGB to YUV 420P image in Go (more precisely `*image.RGBA` to `*image.YcbCr`). I havn't found any standard method in `image` package for that. As I also didn't find any library for that, my only idea was to make it pixel by pixel using `color.RGBToYCbCr()`, but I realised that `*image.YcbCr` hasn't `Set()` method for working directly on pixels, so I'm a bit confused. I would be gratuful for some directions or code for that.
Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `image.NewYCbCr()` to create an instance of `image.YCbCr` whose pixels you can directly manipulate. Then it is just a matter of using `color.RGBToYCbCr()` for each pixel in the image:

```
bounds := original.Bounds()
converted := image.NewYCbCr(bounds, image.YCbCrSubsampleRatio420)

for row := 0; row < bounds.Max.Y; row++ {
    for col := 0; col < bounds.Max.X; col++ {
        r, g, b, _ := original.At(col, row).RGBA()
        y, cb, cr := color.RGBToYCbCr(uint8(r), uint8(g), uint8(b))

        converted.Y[converted.YOffset(col, row)] = y
        converted.Cb[converted.COffset(col, row)] = cb
        converted.Cr[converted.COffset(col, row)] = cr
    }
}
```

In the snippet above `original` is a regular `image.RGBA` and `converted` is `image.YCbCr`. See that the corresponding position `pos` in the arrays of the color components of `converted` is computed from the pixel coordinates in `original`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, this is what I'm looking for, but as I specified in question, target format is YUV 420, so I change declaration of `converted` to `image.NewYCbCr(bounds, image.YCbCrSubsampleRatio420)`, but now I am getting `panic: runtime error: index out of range [76800] with length 76800` - I thnik, that `pos` need to be calculated in different way for that format, as there is chroma subsampling active. Do you know how should it be computed?

Comment: @MikolajMGT I see the issue, in fact, `image.YCbCr` provides the methods `YOffset` and `COffset` for that. I updated the answer.